# Recently enabled 2fa for my github account failed to push the code and shows you don't have right access. (Able to clone the project)

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

After enabling 2fa failed to push the code and shows you don't have right access. (Able to clone the project)

I can able to clone the project but failed to push the code in gitub repo. Recently I have enabled the 2fa for my github.

Any solution for this

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: I assume you are using a token to do your pushes to GitHub, since that's pretty much required now. Check your token configuration: does it grant you write access? When you create a token, there are a whole bunch of permissions you can set per token, and it's easy to get it wrong.

Comment: No I am not using any token simply git push origin <branchname>

Comment: I'm surprised that still works. Don't you get an error message saying you should create a token? Or maybe it's still at the warning stage. In any case, check the repo settings and make sure you have write access to it, and make sure the URL is correct, I don't see what else you can do.

Comment: No it says you don't have right access. Can you let me know how can i create and push the code

Comment: I have done 1. Generated key in terminal 2. Copied the pub key and saved in ssh key of my repo 3. Then added the identity and tried to push the code. But it shows failed to push and you do not have right access to push the code

Comment: Then I would inspect the settings of the ssh key you saved to GitHub, and make sure you gave it write permission. While you may have write access to a repo, an individual key you configure can be granted a subset of the rights you have, so make sure it has all the rights you need.

Comment: In the ssh key listed place it shows like read/write for that key.

Comment: I'm stumped, sorry! Maybe try to edit your question and show the exact commands you run, possibly obfuscating your URLs if the repo is private? Show the clone command, then the output of `git remote -v`, then the push command, and the output from all of these.

Comment: Are you using SSH or HTTPS for your remote?  You can see with `git remote get-url origin`.

Comment: I am using ssh for remote

Answer (score 0):

> I am using ssh for remote

Then 2FA is not relevant here, only your SSH setup.

Check the output of:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

As long as you don't see a Welcome message, with your GitHub account username displayed in it, you won't be able to push.
The permission issue mentioned in the comments are only relevant on Linux/Mac, not necessarily on Windows.